# Stop audio loop (audioplayers package)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter programming and I want to create an application, where I need an audio file to play/loop in the background. However it should stop, when double tapping on the screen.

The audio is saved in the assets folder. I am able to play it, but i don't know how to pause/stop it. I am using this [package](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md).

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    audioCache.play('rainsound.mp3', );
    return new Scaffold(
      child: new GestureDetector(
        onDoubleTap: () {
          //here I would like to stop the audio
          debugPrint('audio stopped');
        },
```

Comment: Did you try `audioCache.clearCache()`?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error: "The method 'stop' was called on null."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Update (`audioplayers v1.0.1`)

##### To Play:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
```

```dart
// Assuming you have the file in "assets/audio/my_audio.mp3"
player.play(AssetSource('audio/my_audio.mp3'));
```

##### To Stop:

```dart
audioPlayer.stop();
```

---

You will have to get the instance of `AudioPlayer` to stop the file, simply use await on `play()` to get the instance and using this, you can call `stop()`. This is the working code.

```
AudioCache cache; // you have this
AudioPlayer player; // create this

void _playFile() async{
  player = await cache.play('my_audio.mp3'); // assign player here
}

void _stopFile() {
  player?.stop(); // stop the file like this
}
```

Comment: What is that `?` for?

Comment: `?.` is used to check null, so `stop()` will be called only if `player != null`.

Comment: Coooool, we learn new things everyday. And I don't know. I'm not the one who asked the question, just wanted to know.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: Hey, @CopsOnRoad. I did notice that you rejected my edit because `play and loop are 2 different things`. I'm aware of it. If you pay attention to the question's title, you'll notice that OP is actually looping the audio, not only playing, although he/she is using the `play()` method in the example code.

Comment: @HugoPassos Yes, you are right, in title, OP asked for `loop` but in code he used `play` which is why I rejected your edit. Hope you didn't mind that.

Comment: Is there any way to pause an resume the AudioCache?

Comment: Does it only work on mp3 audios, since i used the exact same code for my audio and then i cannot hear any sound of my audio any more, neither i can hear/play nor i can stop it