# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'play' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter programming, I was trying to build an audio player app and I am using the [audioplayers](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers) package. I want to create two buttons, one for playing the audio and the other to stop the audio.
What have I tried:
I referred to this thread [Stop playing audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360083/stop-audio-loop-audioplayers-package) and did the same but got this error:

```
E/flutter (18681): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'play' was called on null. 
E/flutter (18681): Receiver: null 
E/flutter (18681): Tried calling: play("audio/blind.mp3")
```

My code:

```
AudioCache cache;  
AudioPlayer player;

.
.
.
.
child: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  player = await cache.play('audio/blind.mp3');
                }
.
.
.
.
. 
child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                   player?.stop();
                   print('working');
                }
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize your variable `cache`. You should do something like this inside an `initState` or in a `build` method to ensure your object is not `null` :

```dart
cache = AudioCache();
```